# Define continuity for $f(x)=\arctan(2x^3)/x^2$ at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\dfrac{\arctan(2x^3)}{x^2}.$$

1. How are we allowed to define $f(x)$ at $x=0$ for it to be continuous there?
2. Find the derivative for all $x$ real numbers.

I can't see this work out since $x=0$ is not defined in the denominator.

Thanks beforehand if anyone can explain :)

Comment: Note that the whole expression is absolute value.

Comment: **Hint:** What can you say about $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\arctan(2x^3)}{x^2}\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{\arctan(2x^3)}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Compute the limit $$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan ( 2x^3 )}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^3}{x^2}=0.$$ Hence we define $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)$ is continuous.
Now compute the derivative. For $x\ne 0$, we have \begin{align}
  & f'(x)=\frac{{( \arctan ( 2x^3 ))^{\prime }}\cdot x^2-\arctan( 2x^3)\cdot{ (x^2)^{\prime }}}{(x^2)^2}=\frac{\frac{6x^4}{1+4x^6}-2x\arctan(2x^3)}{x^4} \\ 
 & =\frac{6}{1+4x^2}-\frac{2\arctan ( 2x^3 )}{x^3}.  \tag1
\end{align}
And $$f'(0)= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\frac{\arctan( 2x^3)}{x^2}-0}{x-0} =\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\arctan ( 2x^3t)}{x^3} =\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x^3}{x^3}=2.$$
Or we can simply let $x$ tends to zero in $(1)$.

Comment: This is the worst MathJax coding I've ever seen, and I've seen some atrocious stuff.  You've got \underset{x\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\, where you could just write \lim_{x\to 0} and lots of similarly bad things. For example, \left({{x}^{3}}\right) where you could have (x^3). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used Mathtype to help me produce a formula. Yes, it is often awkward.

Comment: Thanks! However, isn't f(0) a 0/0 case? Or can we say it is defined due to the two sided limit?

Comment: @mathgrad93 The given expression is not defined at $x = 0$, and we are to determine a value at $x = 0$, so that the function is continuous on the whole real line. That is, just compute the (two sided) limit.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\arctan (2x^3)}{x^2}$$

to find what happens when $x$ aproaches zero both sides.

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

As for the derivarive

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= x^{-2}\arctan(2x^3) \Rightarrow \\f'(x) &= -2x^{-3}\arctan(2x^3) + x^{-2}\frac{6x^2}{1+4x^6} \\&= \frac{6}{1+4x^6}-\frac{2\ \arctan(2x^3)}{x^3} \end{align}$$

What happens when $x \to 0$?

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function initially defined is in fact undefined when $x=0$ because the numerator and denominator are both $0$.  The question is how to define it at $0$ so as to make it continuous at $0$.  That means that what is asked for is a function of the form
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if }x\ne0,\\ c & \text{if }x=0, \end{cases}
$$
and such that $g$ is continuous at $0$.  That means the number $c$ must be $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$.

A limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\bullet}\dfrac{{}\  \bullet\  {}}\bullet$ where both the numerator and the denominator approach $0$ can be $0$ or any other number or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, depending on which functions are in the numerator and the denominator.